# Display vue component in laravel blade template

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I am doing a simple calculation in app.js. It just multiplies the product price by quantity. I want to display the total value in laravel, so a user can preview their order.

app.js

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#item',
    data() {
        return {
            form: {
                price: 0,
                quantity: 0,
                total: 0
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        updatePrice(event) {
            this.form.price = event.target.value;
            this.form.total = this.form.price * this.form.quantity
        },
        updateQuantity(event) {
            this.form.quantity = event.target.value;
            this.form.total = this.form.price * this.form.quantity
        }
    }
```

This is fine. They calculate the form value in blade file. But how I can display the total?

[image: total price]

I want to display the '`total`' in blade file.  How can I access that? When I use `@{{ total }}` I get this error:

> app.js:36519 [Vue warn]: Property or method "total" is not defined on
>   the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this
>   property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based
>   components, by initializing the property.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Typically you would use [**template interpolations**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Interpolations) for that.

Something like `{{ form.total }}`, which in a Blade template, to overcome the usage of `{{`, it would be:

```
<div id="item">
  <p>Total is: @{{ form.total }}</p>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can **change Vue's delimiters** and workaround this issue. For example (`delimiters: ['!{', '}!'],`):

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#item',
    delimiters: ['!{', '}!'],
    data() {
        return {
            form: {
                price: 1,
                quantity: 1,
                total: 1
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        updatePrice(event) {
            this.form.price = event.target.value;
            this.form.total = this.form.price * this.form.quantity
        },
        updateQuantity(event) {
            this.form.quantity = event.target.value;
            this.form.total = this.form.price * this.form.quantity
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="item">
  <p>Total is: !{ form.total }!</p>
  price: <input @input="updatePrice"><br>
  quantity: <input @input="updateQuantity"><br>
</div>
```

Although that would work, in your case, instead of handling events directly, I suggest using `v-model` in `price` and `quantity` and creating `total` as a [**computed property**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html). This would be an approach that better uses Vue's capabilities (and is less code, yay):

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#item',
    data() {
        return {
            form: {
                price: 1,
                quantity: 1,
                total: 1
            }
        }
    },
    computed: {
        total() {
            return this.form.price * this.form.quantity
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="item">
  <p>Total is: {{ total }}</p>
  price: <input v-model="form.price"><br>
  quantity: <input v-model="form.quantity"><br>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried this. It works fine in normal JS but when I use it in blade, this doesn't work. I use @ sign to bypass the blade rendering

Comment: Ah, yes. In blade it would be something like: `<p>Total is: @{{ form.total }}</p>`. Is this what you have tried?

Comment: Exactly. This doesn't work, I shows nothing. I guess the dom isn't updating

Comment: Yes, you can try changing the delimiters too, via `delimiters: ['!{', '}!'],` and using like `<p>Total is: !{ form.total }!</p>`, see updated answer. Maybe you could try this one to see if the problem is other.

Comment: Thank you. I solve it using {{ form.total }}

What a dumb I am! Thanks for commenting

Comment: Alright, good to know. Not dumb at all. Sometimes all it takes is a second pair of eyes. :D